# Mobile inventory application -- need advice

Tags: windows-mobile

I have been tasked with designing an application for tracking inventory on a mobile device.  The application will be barcode scanner enabled and either make real time service calls (preferred) or periodic file transfers to update our backend system written in ASP.NET.  We are a .NET shop so we will likely leverage the Microsoft platform.  Of significant importance is that our prototype is scheduled for delivery in Sept 2010.

The advice I am seeking is in regards to which mobile platform we should target.  Given the timeframe of the prototype, I believe that Mobile 7 will not be released.

That leaves Mobile 6.5 (and earlier) and CE 5.0.

Having not developed a mobile app in a long time, I am not familiar with the platforms so it is hard for me to compare between them.  Given the (very) high level requirements, does one platform seem more logical than the other?

Thanks,

Steve

Comment: CE 5.0 and Windows Mobile 6.x are not in the same category. Is your application going to work on Mobile phones that you go and buy from a regular cellular supplier?

Comment: I was hoping to make the platform decision prior to deciding on the device.  The quick answer is no, these will be commercial devices with barcode scanners attached (such as: http://goo.gl/cJoD)

Comment: We have decided to go with a Motorola device running CE.  The functionality provided by the SDK coupled with the support options they have in place made the decision pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want this to run a single app (i.e. no users playing around with other parts of the OS) I'd go with a Motorola scanner running Windows CE. CE is a lot easier to lock down to kiosk mode than WinMo, and with your schedule, you don't want to be burning cycles trying to get kiosk mode working.